# How to use PayPal iOS SDK to split payments to various people?

Tags: paypal

Suppose i have an app and a website that offers people to sell finger drawings made on their phones.

People create finger paintings on iPhone and upload it to a website in which they can view all
of their drawings and associate prices with these drawings.

Suppose each drawing has a QR Code tied to it to identify it and its price. And i see it in real life and i want to buy it. I scan it, pay for it through paypal.

But how will paypal redirect this money to -> owner of that product set.

What i need is a system in which each transaction knows whose account the money is being directed to. Lets say I have 10 various qr codes according to the 10 drawings. This product set needs to have something associated with it so that when they are scanned, paypal money flows to that product set owner.

Also, these drawings owners/product set owners must be able to withdraw money from the aforesaid html website.

Answer (score 1):

Paypal Adaptive payments option has two options for this.

1. Chained payments
2. Parallel payments.

Please refer to : https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro

However, current iOS SDK - which is in beta status (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro) - does not support these features. (as on 21 March 2013)

One option is to use paypal APIs directly, or implement the flow using a webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try with MPL which is also recommend by PayPal  https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/blob/gh-pages/MPL/PayPalMPL_2-1-0_iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link where I have written complete flow to integrate delayed chain payment in iPhone.

[iOS PayPal integration with backend chained payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149377/ios-paypal-integration-with-backend-chained-payments/29538781#29538781)